# How to remove extra space between page and footer poi java

Tags: apache-poi

I am creating a poi word document . I have setup page margin 0 but their is extra space between bottom and footer image i want to remove this space. I have used this code which did not work

```
  addNewPgMar.setLeft(BigInteger.valueOf(0));
  addNewPgMar.setRight(BigInteger.valueOf(210));
  addNewPgMar.setGutter(BigInteger.valueOf(0));
  addNewPgMar.setFooter(BigInteger.valueOf(0));
  addNewPgMar.setHeader(BigInteger.valueOf(0));
```

[image]

I want to remove this footer below space which is showing in image.

Comment: You should get used to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your questions. Else you might get reluctant response like down votes, closing votes or negative comments.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem has nothing to do with the page margins but with the paragraph settings in the footer. A `Word` paragraph has settings for spacing after each paragraph as well as for spacing between the lines in the paragraph. If the picture in your footer is inline in a paragraph in the footer, then the spacing after the paragraph must be 0 and the spacing between must be 1 to avoid the spacing you are facing.

Using `apache poi 4.1.0` this can be set using:

```
...
XWPFParagraph paragraph...
...
paragraph.setSpacingAfter(0);
paragraph.setSpacingBetween(1d, LineSpacingRule.AUTO);
...
```

Complete example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.wp.usermodel.HeaderFooterType;
import org.apache.poi.util.Units;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTSectPr;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTPageSz;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTPageMar;

import java.math.BigInteger;

public class CreateWordHeaderFooterNullMargin {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

  // the body content
  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The Body");

  // create header start
  XWPFHeader header = document.createHeader(HeaderFooterType.DEFAULT);
  paragraph = header.getParagraphArray(0);
  if (paragraph == null) paragraph = header.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setSpacingAfter(0);
  paragraph.setSpacingBetween(1d, LineSpacingRule.AUTO);
  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The Header");

  // create footer start
  XWPFFooter footer = document.createFooter(HeaderFooterType.DEFAULT);
  paragraph = footer.getParagraphArray(0);
  if (paragraph == null) paragraph = footer.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
  paragraph.setSpacingAfter(0);
  paragraph.setSpacingBetween(1d, LineSpacingRule.AUTO);
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  String imgFile="Chrysanthemum.jpg";
  run.addPicture(new FileInputStream(imgFile), XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG, imgFile, Units.toEMU(500), Units.toEMU(25));

  // create page margins
  CTSectPr sectPr = document.getDocument().getBody().getSectPr();
  if (sectPr == null) sectPr = document.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();
  CTPageSz pageSz = sectPr.addNewPgSz(); // paper format letter
  pageSz.setW(BigInteger.valueOf(12240)); //12240 Twips = 12240/20 = 612 pt = 612/72 = 8.5"
  pageSz.setH(BigInteger.valueOf(15840)); //15840 Twips = 15840/20 = 792 pt = 792/72 = 11"
  CTPageMar pageMar = sectPr.getPgMar();
  if (pageMar == null) pageMar = sectPr.addNewPgMar();
  pageMar.setLeft(BigInteger.valueOf(720)); //720 TWentieths of an Inch Point (Twips) = 720/20 = 36 pt = 36/72 = 0.5"
  pageMar.setRight(BigInteger.valueOf(720));
  pageMar.setTop(BigInteger.valueOf(0));
  pageMar.setBottom(BigInteger.valueOf(0));
  pageMar.setFooter(BigInteger.valueOf(0));
  pageMar.setHeader(BigInteger.valueOf(0));
  pageMar.setGutter(BigInteger.valueOf(0));

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateWordHeaderFooterNullMargin.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

 }
}
```

Disclaimer: In my opinion page settings where margins are 0 are not recommendable. Most printers are not able printing the full paper's size. There are printable areas with minimal spaces on left, right, top and/or bottom of the paper. If you set page margins 0, then `Word`'s `GUI` will warn about this. If you ignore that warning then you possible can damage the printer while next printing. Most printers will not print into their not printable page ranges even if you told to do so. That is to avoid that damaging.