# Remove a paragraph from a footer in a Word document

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have created a footer on the document that includes a table with one row and three columns but below the table there is an empty paragraph that makes the footer larger than I want. I read someone that said to set up the margins of the document but I am already doing that and they all work apart from the bottom margin.

This is the method

```
 static public void footer(XWPFDocument doc) {

    CTSectPr sectPr = doc.getDocument().getBody().getSectPr() == null ? doc.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr() : doc.getDocument().getBody().getSectPr();
    XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy footerPolicy= new XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy(doc, sectPr);

    XWPFFooter footer = footerPolicy.createFooter(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.DEFAULT);

    // create table in footer
    XWPFParagraph paragraph = footer.createParagraph();

    XmlCursor cursor = paragraph.getCTP().newCursor();
    XWPFTable table = footer.insertNewTbl(cursor);
    XWPFTableRow row = (table.getRow(0) == null)? table.createRow() : table.getRow(0);

    int twips = 1440;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        XWPFTableCell cell = row.getCell(i);
        if (cell == null) cell = row.createCell();
        CTTblWidth tblWidth = cell.getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewTcW();
        tblWidth.setW(BigInteger.valueOf(((i == 1) ? 3 : 2) * twips));
        tblWidth.setType(STTblWidth.DXA);
        paragraph = cell.getParagraphs().get(0);
        XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
        if (i == 0) {
            paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);
            run.setText("blah blah blah");
        } else if (i == 1) {
            paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
            paragraph.getCTP().addNewFldSimple().setInstr("PAGE \\* MERGEFORMAT");
        } else if (i == 2) {
            paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.RIGHT);
            run.setText("blah blah blah");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the next footer. I've typed "Empty line" and added the borders of the table , so I guess is clearer what my problem is.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There always must be a paragraph below a table. This paragraph cannot be removed. Try removing it in `Word`'s `GUI`. It will not be possible.

So all you could do is shrinking the paragraph's height by set a very low default font size (1pt at minimum) and set spacing after that paragraph to 0.

```
...
XWPFParagraph paragraph = footer.createParagraph();
paragraph.getCTP().addNewPPr().addNewRPr().addNewSz().setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(2)); // default font size 2 half pt = 1pt
paragraph.setSpacingAfter(0);
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it reduced the size of the paragraph. However, it's still quite big. Manually, I can go to the footer design and I can see it's set up to 1.27 cm, so if can't change that with POI the users will have to do it manually :). Thanks again!

Comment: @Nils: Header and footer margins and spacing are part of the page settings. And of course it is possible to set page margins using `apache poi`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57340121/how-to-remove-extra-space-between-page-and-footer-poi-java/57340971#57340971 for example. But that was not the question here.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I saw that post before and tried but somehow I missed the setFooter and I was trying to change the bottom margin. Then, I assumed that I wasn't able to change the footer, that's why my question. I have a method to set up the margins and I added it there. Works like a charm. Thanks a lot!